# add Android SDK from AOSP to Intellij

Tags: android, android-source

Just compiled android 8.0 source code. I'm fairly new to AOSP.
It is quite confusing, the ./out contains a lot of files.

Currently, i couldn't create android project on Intellij yet, because i haven't specify the android SDK.

I want to add my customized ROM as android SDK to Intellij, instead of downloading SDKs.

Does anyone had similar experience loading their own ROM to android app IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to trigger a SDK built, e.g.

```
$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch sdk_x86_64-eng
$ m -j sdk
```

Afterwards, you have your SDK at `out/host/darwin-x86/sdk/sdk_x86_64`. Point your Android Studio SDK location (in Project Settings) to that folder and you should be good to go. You might need to install the required build tools, but the IDE prompts for it in case.